# ¿Podrá la RAE actualizarse y agregar nuevas palabras a la lengua tan rápido como aparecen?

Tags: rae

¿Cuánto tiempo se toma la RAE en aprobar una palabra que ya esta bajo su consideración de ser agregada a la lengua? ¿Puede la RAE actualizar el lenguaje y apoyar las demandas del nuevo vocabulario de la tecnología, por ejemplo? ¿Cómo gestiona la RAE adiciones tan relativamente rápidas al lenguaje?

Comment: Gracias por la liga. Esta usted sugiriendo que se usaria la nueva palabra con entrecomillado o cursiva pero que la RAE no ha hecho ningun tipo de actualizaciones a su sistema para aceptar nuevas palabras, por ejemplo las del campo computacional, cuya tecnologia puede cambiar cada 3 meses trayendo varias palabras nuevas?

Comment: es que la RAE se ha fijado como criterio esperar a que los neologismos se consoliden en el uso general unos diez años como mínimo antes de integrarlos al Diccionario usual. De lo contrario, el diccionario quedaría enorme.

Comment: Diez años es un largo tiempo. Gracias.